# Upgrade Grails version

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

I have a grails project that is at version 2.3.4 and I need to upgrade to the latest version possible. Looking at the documentation I realized that from 2.x to 3.x there are huge changes.

The question is: is it ideal for me to do this gradual upgrade from 2 to 3 from 3 to 4 and from 4 to 5 or is it better/possible to do this from 2 to 5 at once?

Answer (score 5):

> The question is: is it ideal for me to do this gradual upgrade from 2
> to 3 from 3 to 4 and from 4 to 5 or is it better/possible to do this
> from 2 to 5 at once?

Generally speaking it will be better to go from 2 to 5.  The effort to go from 2 to 3 is about the same as going from 2 to 5.  Introducing the interim upgrades will be more work to end up at the same place.

Answer (score 3):

If your end-goal is to have a modern Grails application, I would go from 2 to 5 directly. There have been numerous upgrades from 2 to 4 recently, and probably from 2 to 5 onwards - so there is a decent amount of information about it to be found.

Doing it stepwise means you have to first find info for 2 to 3, then 3 to 4 and finally 4 to 5. I think that will cause you more trouble than it is worth.

Comment: We have done many many of these upgrades, and the comments above are consistent with our experience.

Answer (score 0):

Jeff is wrong in saying its easier to go from 2 to 5. There are swathes of code and classes removed and changed. 2 to 3 is a far easier transition. PLUS, 3 is based on Springboot so if you have any problems, you can easily transition into the most widely used Java Framework and just use Groovy with it. :)

Comment: "Jeff is wrong in saying its easier to go from 2 to 5. There are swathes of code and classes removed and changed. 2 to 3 is a far easier transition." - I don't think the question is whether it is easier to go from 2 to 3 or from 2 to 5.  I think the question is it easier to go from 2 to 3 to 4 to 5 vs going from 2 to 5.  It is practically indisputable that it is easier to go straight to 5 from 2, and that is based on a lot of experience with these projects.

Comment: I think it is 'indesputable' that you want people off older versions... yes. Thats the only thing thats 'indesputable'. But the vast majority of issues and errors on Stackoverflow are from 4&5. 3 is EXTREMELY stable due to its reliance on Springboot.